# What is the simplest way to get all child that have specific value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get all children from "users" at `level 1`. What is the simplest way to do it?

I already made the Constructor, Getter and Setter, And `ListView`, but I still can't understand the code. I want to understand the code so I can modify it myself.

Comment: Share what you've done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all users at `level 1`, you need to use a query. So please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query levelQuery = rootRef.child("users").orderByChild("level").equalTo(1);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String username = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, username);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
levelQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
user1
```

P.S. You should consider storing user data under the user id and not under that pushed id. Storing credentials in plain text is not such a good idea. I recommend you implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) so you can secure you database using [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). If you want to keep your own authentication mechanism, please see the official document regarding that:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

**For Java**

```
FirebaseDatabase mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDbUserRef= mRootRef.getReference("users");

mDbUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            HashMap<String, String> data = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String level = data.get("level");
            //check level here and add to array list 
            if(level.equals("1")){
                //if level == 1 than add data to array list
            }
        }

        //notify listview here after array filled with data.

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
    });
```

**For Kotlin**

```
val mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var mDbUserRef= mRootRef.getReference("users")

mDbUserRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    for (child in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val data = child.value as HashMap<String, String>
                        val level = data["level"]
                        if (level.equals("1")){
                            //if level == 1 than add data to array list
                        }
                        //notify listview here after array filled with data.
                    }
                }
            })
```